# Count Distinct with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to change the count DISTINCT portion of the query below, because the current query returns WINDOW definition is not supported.  What is most seamless way to do this calc using PostgreSQL?  Thank you.

```
SELECT transaction_date, brand, Description, Amount, newval
into temp.table
FROM (SELECT transaction_date, brand, Description, Amount,
         (Amount / count(DISTINCT unique_mem_id) over (partition by to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM'),brand
         )) as newval
  FROM source.table
 )
WHERE DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%Criteria%';
```

Comment: can you give sample input and output

Comment: I'm really trying to ask how to do conduct a Count Distinct calculation using PostgreSQL.

Comment: `partition by to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM')` You dont need to convert to char here, just use date_trunc: `partition by date_trunc('month', transaction_date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the use-case it seems better to split the code.

Create a table **month_brand** based on the following query:

```
select      to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM')    as yyyymm
           ,brand
           ,count (distinct unique_mem_id)          as count_distinct_unique_mem_id

from        source.table

group by    yyyymm
           ,brand
;
```

Join **month_brand** with your source table:

```
select      t.transaction_date, t.brand, t.Description, t.Amount, t.Amount / m.count_distinct_unique_mem_id as newval

from                    source.table    as t

            join        month_brand     as m

            on          m.yyyymm = to_char(t.transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM')    

where       t.description ilike '%Criteria%'
;
```

---

Instead of `count(distinct ...)`, 2 phase solution:

1. give row numbers to the duplicated unique_mem_id
2. count only the unique_mem_id with row_number = 1

---

```
select  *

into     temp.table

from   (SELECT  transaction_date, brand, Description, Amount, 
                (Amount / count(case rn when 1 then unique_mem_id end) over (partition by to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM'),brand)) as newval

        FROM    (SELECT     transaction_date, brand, Description, Amount,unique_mem_id
                            row_numner () over (partition by to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM'),brand,unique_mem_id) as rn

                 FROM       source.table
                 )
        )

WHERE   DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%Criteria%'
;
```

Comment: Hi @ZJAY, Please take a look at the solution.

Comment: Solution returned ERROR: column "unique_mem_id" does not exist in derived_table1

Comment: If unique_mem_id  cannot be null then there is no need to select it in the inner query, and it should replaced int the count with any constant, e.g. **1**.

Comment: Thank you Dudu, very helpful.  One final question.  I will run this query 80-100 times a day, each with a different WHERE   DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%_%' (final part of query).  The query runs across 100s of millions of rows, so it is inefficient to run the non-unique part of the query repeatedly (the Count Distinct is same across all queries).  Is there a way where I can run the Count Distinct portion once, perhaps in a separate table, but preserve the results I am seeking.  The key will be to partition the correct YYYY-MM for each relevant row without running the partition in each query.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll be avaiable to answer tomorrow.

Comment: @ZJAY, P.s. do you have something in the source table that is guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @ZJAY, Just verifying, a column called **unique_mem_id** is **not** unique?

Comment: @ZJAY, You could and you should separate the code to 2 queries (I'll edit my answer), but in any case why are you running the code 100 times? why not retrieve all requested descriptions in a single run?

Comment: @ZJAY. P.s. since this is a correct answer to your answer, please mark it as such. Thanks.